# React-Select with React-Apollo does not work

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, react-select

We are using react-select and fetching the items as the user types. I am not able to make it work with react-apollo.

Can someone help me provide a guideline?

Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
class PatientSearchByPhone extends Component {
  updateProp = mobile => {
    if (mobile.length < 10) return;
    this.props.data.refetch({ input: { mobile } });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.data);
    return <AsyncSelect cacheOptions loadOptions={this.updateProp} />;
  }
}

const FETCH_PATIENT = gql`
  query Patient($input: PatientSearchInput) {
    getPatients(input: $input) {
      id
      first_name
    }
  }
`;
export default graphql(FETCH_PATIENT, {
  options: ({ mobile }) => ({ variables: { input: { mobile } } })
})(PatientSearchByPhone);
```

Versions:
"react-apollo": "^2.1.11",
"react-select": "^2.1.0"

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a sample at https://codesandbox.io ?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I've just started looking at this integration and curious how others have approached it.

Comment: @AllenFuller yeah, I did. Let me create a sandbox example for you later today.

Comment: @AllenFuller added an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got an e-mail asking a response to this question. It reminds me of this XKCD comics:

[image: Never have I felt so close to another soul]

I do not recall the exact solution I implemented, so I setup a complete example for this.

This app (code snippet below) kickstarts searching as soon as you type 4 characters or more in the input box (You are expected to type artist's name. Try `vinci`?). Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";
import ApolloClient, { gql } from "apollo-boost";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://metaphysics-production.artsy.net"
});

const fetchArtists = async (input: string, cb: any) => {
  if (input && input.trim().length < 4) {
    return [];
  }
  const res = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        match_artist(term: "${input}") {
          name
          imageUrl
        }
      }
    `
  });

  if (res.data && res.data.match_artist) {
    return res.data.match_artist.map(
      (a: { name: string; imageUrl: string }) => ({
        label: a.name,
        value: a.imageUrl
      })
    );
  }

  return [];
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [artist, setArtist] = useState({
    label: "No Name",
    value: "https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff&text=No+Artist"
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h4>Search artists and their image (type 4 char or more)</h4>
        <AsyncSelect
          loadOptions={fetchArtists}
          onChange={(opt: any) => setArtist(opt)}
          placeholder="Search an Artist"
          className="select"
        />
        <div>
          <img alt={artist.label} src={artist.value} className="aimage" />
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You can clone https://github.com/naishe/react-select-apollo it is a working example. I have deployed the app here: https://apollo-select.naishe.in/, may be play a little?

Comment: This is great @Nishant - how would you go about preselecting an artist based on id?

Comment: There are `defaultOptions` and `defaultValue` to play with.

Comment: @Nishant You saved my life/job. Thanks, man! <3

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to execute the graphql query manually using the `client` that is exposed by wrapping the base component with `withApollo`.

In the example below, we have,

1. BaseComponnent which renders the AsyncSelect `react-select` component
2. `loadOptionsIndexes` which executes the async graphql fetch via the `client`
3. BaseComponent.propTypes describes the required `client` prop
4. `withApollo` wraps the base component to give us the actual component we'll use elsewhere in the react app.

```
const BaseComponent = (props) => {
  const loadOptionsIndexes = (inputValue) => {
    let graphqlQueryExpression = {
      query: QUERY_INDEXES,
      variables: {
        name: inputValue
      }
    }

    const transformDataIntoValueLabel = (data) => {
      return data.indexes.indexes.map(ix => { return { value: ix.id, label: ix.name }})
    } 

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      props.client.query(graphqlQueryExpression).then(response => {
        resolve(transformDataIntoValueLabel(response.data))
      })
    });

  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="chart-buttons-default">
        <div className="select-index-input" style={{width: 400, display: "inline-block"}}>
          <AsyncSelect 
            isMulti={true}
            cacheOptions={true}
            defaultOptions={true}
            loadOptions={loadOptionsIndexes} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

BaseComponent.propTypes = {
  client: PropTypes.any,
}

const ComplementComponent = withApollo(BaseComponent);
```

Sorry if the example is a little off - copy and pasted what I had working rather than moving on without giving back.